# ASP.NET application SQL connection error from production server

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

During development on my local computer, I am able to connect to the remote (Production) SQL Server with no issues, but when I deploy the application to said production server, I get this error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.

I have done I believe all the things suggested to resolve this problem with no success. Please help if you can. Thanks!

Comment: Please add a redacted version of your connection string being used to connect to the database instance and a code snippet of where you try to connect.

Comment: What are "all the things" that you tried?

Comment: 1. Make sure SQL Server Service is running
2. Make sure SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections
3. Enabled TCP/IP
<add name="DBConnection" connectionString="data source=SASQL-PROD;initial catalog=FulfillmentPortal;persist security info=True;Integrated Security=false;user id=User;password=Password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: More information is necessary. Where is your production database and where is your production web server? Are they both hosted by Azure, AWS, GoDaddy, self-hosted, etc? Typically if your database is hosted in a cloud service there is a whitelist of IP addresses and/or resources that can access the database.

Comment: Install SQL Server Management Studio on Server so you can remotely connect to a database.  The verify using SSMS you can connect to database.  Error is due to credentials not being correct.  Need to see connection string.  First do not use Attach (mdf file) in connection string it is not needed the database is already attached.  The use Integrated Security = true which will use windows credentials.  The make the windows user group same on local and remote PCs.  Then put users into group.  If you are on a corporate network using Group Policy there are groups already setup.  See your MIS.

Comment: SQL is installed on self hosted corporate server. I also have SSMS installed on local computer and I am connected to remote server.

Comment: Can you access the production application server? I assume it is also self-hosted, but probably a separate virtual server. Make sure you can ping the database server from that machine, make sure the correct firewall ports are open on the database server.

Comment: Yes, I can access the production application server.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer to my issue. I am using ASP.NET Identity and it created it's own connection but I wanted to use my own database. When I deployed my application that connection was broken. Changed the Identity connection to my own database connection and all worked as expected.